# Missing plots after for loop

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I have a dataset that I want to plot, and also do a linear regression on the data in some invervals, plotting it in the same graph. 
But I have some problems with this... The main graph is plotted first, the intervals and the linear regression in the for loop:

```
plt.plot(Trec, lnp, 'r-')

for i in range(len(Werte)):
    plt.plot( subset(Time, Trec, Data[i][5], Data[i][6])[1], subset(Time, Trec, Data[i][5], Data[i][6])[1] * Data[i][2] + Data[i][4])
    plt.axvline(x=Data[i][5])

plt.show()
```

With this code it only plots me the last iteration of the for loop. By itself, the commands all do what I intend them to do... What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want is superimposing figures on the same plot. For that purpose, you can use the axis object returned by subplots.

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(...) # plot your data here
ax.plot(...) # plot your interval and regression here.
plt.show()
```